# Move files to another folder using C#

Tags: c#, file-io, directory

My source path is `C:\doc\` in which I have pdf files.
What I want to do is create an application that will check `C:\doc\` every so often and then move files automatically from that folder to another location without clicking the application every time I want to move files. I want when a file comes to `c:\doc` will the application discover the file or files and move them to for example `C:\doc2\` automatically. I hope you understand me what I mean.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Any effort so far? .NET has `File.Move` method. And you can schedule your program in a _Task Scheduler_ for check every minutes for example..

Comment: Have you done anything so far? Don't expect us to do your homework.

Comment: you can use FileSystemWatcher,  but a winservice should be better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect when a file is added to the folder use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To move a file use the [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Perhaps something like this?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = @"C:\doc";
        var target = @"C:\doc2";
        while (true)
        {
            using (var folderWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(source))
            {
                folderWatcher.Filter = "*.*";

                Console.WriteLine("Watching " + source);
                var change = folderWatcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, 1000 * 60);

                if (!change.TimedOut)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File detected: " + change.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Moving to: " + target);
                    File.Move(Path.Combine(source, change.Name), Path.Combine(target, change.Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I will thank you. It's working perfekt. Thank you very much and others poeple. You are wonderful.

Comment: What does mean 1000*60 in change? I will have this program in startup and want watching allaways until I Close my computer. It can be the hole day. 1000*60 is that mean limit time going to  Watch c:\doc?

Comment: @JonasWillander Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: If you mean about Task Scheduler  , yes I did and created a new Task Scheduler for everyday but stil the same problem. Files not movied if the program runs some minutes (maybe one or two minutes). I selected "Daily" in my Task Scheduler.

Comment: The program has an infinite loop so it should keep running until cancelled.

Comment: Thank you Vidstige, it's true with infinite loop but I don't know sometimes it's freezing, the files did not move. But another problem is when there is already the same name file on doc2 then the application crashes. inside if(!change.TimeOut) I put those two console.WriteLine and File.Move.... on try and on Catch I just wrote error message like Console.WriteLine("The file already exist"); but still freezing after error. I really appreciate for your help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Windows Service` which runs in the background. Your job is to program it so, that the service copies the files each x timespan.

As shown in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) document:

> Microsoft Windows services, formerly known as NT services, enable you to create long-running executable applications that run in their own Windows sessions. These services can be automatically started when the computer boots, can be paused and restarted, and do not show any user interface.

So your service will run without anyone needed to click the application, it runs in the background.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a small tutorial by Microsoft on how to create such a service.

---

Another option would be to use a scheduled task. This allows for execution of your program on a timely basis. You then would not have to program the time into your program, as the scheduled task does that for you.

An extra thing here, is that you can run the task manually aswell. This allows for execution when needed straight away, as opposed to the service which will only execute on this programmed timespan.

You would still have to write your application, but a console application would do now, rather than creating a service. You can use the [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function as explained in another answer.

See [documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) for information on how to create a scheduled task.

Comment: sounds like horrible overkill to create a service for something like this. Also I would prefer an event driven approach rather than polling as the implementation will be shorter and clearer as well as reducing cpu-consumption and delays.